# Dotnet pulumi An error occurred trying to start process 'pulumi' with working directory '/tmp/automation-2biaety1.30k'. No such file or directory

Tags: .net, pulumi, pulumi-azure

I run pulumi in dotnet 6 project.

I didn't specify the path for stack work directory, that is fine because it will automatically create a folder in **/tmp** folder.

Everything is ok when I run the project on Windows. But I got a problem when run it in a Linux docker container.

What happen is that pulumi has created the /tmp/automation-xxxxxxx folder, and I can see the **pulumi.yaml** and **pulumi.{env}.yaml** files. But it just **CAN NOT** find the working directory when I was trying to create the stack

```
type=Win32Exception;exception.message=An error occurred trying to start process 'pulumi' with working directory '/tmp/automation-2biaety1.30k'. No such file or directory;exception.stacktrace=An error occurred trying to start process 'pulumi' with working directory '/tmp/automation-2biaety1.30k'. No such file or directory:   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

Comment: maybe a rights issue?